# не удаляються дубликаты из списка

Tags: python, list

нужно чтобы дубликаты убирались

```
f = open("names.txt")
x = [f.read().splitlines()]
f.close()

print(list(set(x)))
```

ошибка:

```
    print(list(set(x)))
  TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: ну так вы пример данных из файла приведите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас в `x` такая структура получается: `x = [['строка файла 1', 'строка файла 2']]`.
Чтобы все работало сделайте так:

```
f = open("names.txt")
x = f.read().splitlines()
f.close()

print(list(set(x)))
```

А лучше так:

```
with open('names.txt') as file:
    x = list(set(file.read().splitlines()))
print(x)
```